# getaddrinfo bind: Address already in use

Tags: c++, linux, macos, sockets

Whenever I attempt to run my app on macOS Catalina 10.15.2 (19C57) or Linux 5.4.3-arch1-1 x86_64 GNU/Linux, I get:

```
_rSockd: bind: Address already in use
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::runtime_error: failed to bind to socket
[1]    31181 abort      Saol/saol
```

Now I have checked for open ports with `sudo netstat -tulp udp` and `sudo lsof -i udp`, but none of these report any applications of mine using these ports. Nothing is currently listening on the port(45100).

I have browsed several similar posts that mentioned adding the `SO_REUSEADDR`, but this did not change anything when I have it or when I don't.
Posts also mentioned checking for something using the port, but I was unable (I believe unless the above commands were the wrong ones to use) to find my ports locked up. I have tried several different ports(currently using 45100); the `_port` var is set to an `int` before the `_Init` function is called. `getaddrinfo`'s second argument is a `const char *service`, and stated in the man pages:

> service sets the port in each returned address structure.  If this
>          argument is a service name (see services(5)), it is translated to the
>          corresponding port number.  This argument can also be specified as a
>          decimal number, which is simply converted to binary.  If service is
>          NULL, then the port number of the returned socket addresses will be
>          left uninitialized.  If AI_NUMERICSERV is specified in hints.ai_flags
>          and service is not NULL, then service must point to a string contain‐
>          ing a numeric port number.  This flag is used to inhibit the invoca‐
>          tion of a name resolution service in cases where it is known not to
>          be required.

All I am doing to the _port is this: `int` -> `string` -> `char *`

Below is the relevant section of my code:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define PORT "45100"

auto main(void) -> int {
  int rv;
  int _rSockd;
  const char * port = std::to_string(8080).c_str();

  struct addrinfo hints;
  struct addrinfo *servinfo;
  struct addrinfo *p;

  memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
  hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
  hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
  hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
  if((rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, port, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
    std::cerr << "getaddrinfo: " << std::endl << gai_strerror(rv) << std::endl;
    throw std::runtime_error("failed to getaddrinfo");
  }

  for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
    if((_rSockd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
      std::perror("_rSockd: socket");
      close(_rSockd);
      continue;
    }

    if(bind(_rSockd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
      close(_rSockd);
      std::perror("_rSockd: bind");
      continue;
    }

    break;
  }

  if(p == NULL) {
    throw std::runtime_error("failed to bind to socket");
  }

  freeaddrinfo(servinfo);

  return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated; I feel I have been staring at it too long and am missing something basic.

**NOTE:** When I added the MCVE (the above updated code), I no longer have my issue when running with port 8080 and 45100. So I will now explain the ??build?? process now to see if this is causing the issue.

**UPDATE**

When I made the MCVE, it worked. It never had the issues from my project base.
My project is a library being called from another executable project. libSaol has the netcode, saol is the executable that links libSaol.

To be honest, this confuses me more...

Comment: Which port number are you attempting to use?  What's already listening on that port?  Are you using the correct functions to set the port number in the correct byte order (`ntoh()` is probably correct for a 16-bit port number — though your code seems to convert it to a string, which doesn't have byte order problems).  You might be running into problems with firewalls.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have updated with requested info, but to be brief: I have attempted several ports, currently I am using 45100; I believe the documentation for `getaddrinfo` for the service argument doesn't need `ntoh`, Beej shows code without it; Firewalls have been checked on both systems and do not have special rules, but have not had issues with other applications(like node running on 8080).

Comment: What happens when you use 8080 instead of 45100?  What happens if you stop the service that's normally running on 8080 and then try to run your code?  Since you've not provided an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
(or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)), it is hard to know what's going wrong.  Silly question: have you checked that no older version of your program is still listening on the port?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler When I added the MCVE and in the process of running it there, I have no issues... In the main text, I have added a small update.

Comment: One of the key requirements of an MCVE is 'Verifiable' — it must reproduce the problem on your system.  (MRE — minimum reproducible example — also has that requirement.) . If what you post doesn't reproduce the problem for you, then there's a crucial difference between it and the non-working version that you need to detect and analyze.